# How to return <Rect/> element back to original position after drag in React + Konva

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

here is my attempt to having a Rect component snap back to its original position (ReactKonva):

```
var toolBarWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.2;
var toolBarHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.2;

class Toolbar extends Component {
    state = {
        x: toolBarWidth / 4,
        y: toolBarHeight / 4
    };
render() {
return (
  <Stage width={toolBarWidth} height={toolBarHeight} fill="red">
    <Layer>
      <Rect width={toolBarWidth} height={toolBarHeight} fill="blue" />

      <Rect
        x={this.state.x}
        y={this.state.y}
        width={toolBarWidth / 5}
        height={toolBarWidth / 5}
        fill="red"
        draggable
        onDragStart={() => {
          console.log("hi");
        }}
        onDragEnd={() => {
          this.setState({ x: toolBarWidth / 4, y: toolBarHeight / 4 });
          this.forceUpdate();
        }}
      />
    </Layer>
  </Stage>
);
}
}

export default Toolbar;
```

So the rectangle's position is set to state.x by default and state.x is toolBarWidth/4. And then at the end of the dragging, I set the state again which I thought would induce another render, but React only renders if it senses update, so setting the state to the same thing again won't work, therefore I did this.forceUpdate(); This doesn't have any luck. Interestingly, if I do this.setState({**1 + toolBarWidth/4**...}) it does work, of course only for the first time.

I feel like there must be some konva way of setting the element's attribute but I couldn't find it. I also tried doing document.getElementId("the canva id") and document.getContext("canva element id") but stopped because I couldn't find a place to define the ID for my canva because it seems to be written into the Stage element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use internal konva methods you have to define refs for each of your **Layer** & **Rectangle**
`<Layer ref="layer">`

`<Rectangle ref="rectangle">`

and use refs in your dragEnd function to set the position of the rectangle to 
`{x: 0, y: 0}`

```
onDragEnd={() => {
  var rectangle = this.refs.rectangle,
      layer = this.refs.layer
  rectangle.position({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  layer.draw()
}}
```

your final JSX code can look like

```
<Stage width={400} height={400} fill="red">
    <Layer ref="layer">
      <Rect width={400} height={400} fill="blue" />
      <Rect
        ref="rectangle"
        x={this.state.x}
        y={this.state.y}
        width={400 / 5}
        height={400 / 5}
        fill="red"
        draggable
        onDragStart={() => {
          console.log("hi");
        }}
        onDragEnd={() => {
          var rectangle = this.refs.rectangle,
              layer = this.refs.layer
          rectangle.position({ x: 0, y: 0 });
          layer.draw()
        }}
      />
    </Layer>
</Stage>
```

Have also created a code sandbox for your reference
https://codesandbox.io/s/set-rectangle-back-to-original-position-on-drag-end-kg9bg

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for!